# Splitting a string into a list of lists of lists using regex

Tags: python, string, list

I have this string:

```
sample_string = 'a,b|a,c;d,e|f,g|a,c;d,e;a,b;f,g'
```

and I'm able to split it up to this point:

```
[['a,b'], ['a,c', 'd,e'], ['f,g'], ['a,c', 'd,e', 'a,b', 'f,g']]
```

with the following code:

```
lista = [[i for i in re.split("[;]| \W]+", s)] for s in re.split("[|]|,\W]+", sample_string)]
```

but my output needs to be in the following manner:

```
[['a,b'], [['a,c'], ['d,e']], ['f,g'], [['a,c'], ['d,e'], ['a,b'], ['f,g']]]
```

I see the pattern that can be [c,c] or [[c,c],[c,c]]
is there a way to make this a recursive function, but still using regex? or even an easier way just with regex?

Comment: Why are you using `re.split()`? Use `split('|')` for one level and `split(':')` for the next level.

Comment: Why is it `['a,b']` rather than `[['a,b']]` like all the other lists?

Comment: A small suggestion regarding the statement of questions on SO generally: it's easiest for readers to understand your question when you state it (clearly, comprehensively and succinctly) before presenting your own faulty code. Here I suggest you move array you wish to return (the last one given) to the top, after defining `sample_string`, with an appropriate preamble.

Comment: If you are using the return value in your code you might find it both more useful and easier to compute if it were, `[[['a,b']], [['a,c'], ['d,e']], [['f,g']], [['a,c'], ['d,e'], ['a,b'], ['f,g']]]`, that is, making `[['a,b']]` and `[['f,g']],` arrays containing a single two-element array, so that all arrays in the return value contained one or more two-element arrays.

Comment: @Barmar To answer your question here.. Why is it ['a,b'] rather than [['a,b']] like all the other lists?  This is a list of joim conditions I'm reading from a csv file, some join conditions only required one key join both tables hence [a,b] but then I have a table that requires a list of keys so I can merge both tables accurately hence [[['a,c'], ['d,e']] that is why the first one is only at level one but the second item has a two level list. hopefully this helps.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank yu very much for the suggestion, I'll be sure to correct that in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursively:

```
def parse(S,d="|;"):
    return [parse(s,d[1:]) for s in S.split(d[0])] if d and d[0] in S else [S]
```

output:

```
sample_string = 'a,b|a,c;d,e|f,g|a,c;d,e;a,b;f,g'

print(parse(sample_string))
[['a,b'], [['a,c'], ['d,e']], ['f,g'], [['a,c'], ['d,e'], ['a,b'], ['f,g']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to write with a `for` loop rather than a list comprehension.

Split the input on `|` characters. Then split each of these on `;`. If that results in a list of just one string (because there was no `;` in that group), you append this list directly to the result. Otherwise, you wrap each of the elements of the second level in another list, and append that to the result.

```
sample_string = 'a,b|a,c;d,e|f,g|a,c;d,e;a,b;f,g'
result = []
for level1 in sample_string.split('|'):
    level2 = level1.split(';')
    if len(level2) == 1:
        result.append(level2)
    else:
        result.append([[item] for item in level2])

print(result)
```

There's no need for recursion because the splitting doesn't continue indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way :

```
lista = [[[x] if len(p.split(";"))>1 else x for x in p.split(";")]
         for p in sample_string.split("|")]
```

Output :

```
print(lista)

#[['a,b'], [['a,c'], ['d,e']], ['f,g'], [['a,c'], ['d,e'], ['a,b'], ['f,g']]]
```

Comment: I'll test it out with my code too :)